# Android простой форматированный текст и картинки

Tags: java, android, xml, android-sdk

Дорогие форумчане, в меня есть вопрос. Каким способом лучше всего выводить отформатированный текст и картинки?
Например, в меня есть статья в формате `.docx` или страница сайта с `HTML` размеченной кодировкой и я хочу сохранить форматирование текста и  все картинки.

И так, сама задача.
У меня есть `Activity`, в котором в меня, например, есть кнопка `Печать` и `Назад`(но это не важно) и область для фрагмента текста. Как мне самым простым и менее затратным способом вставить "статью"?

Например я видел `WebView`, есть ли смысл загружать `.html` файл и отображать так?

Или ещё есть `ScrollView`, можно расставлять `TextView`, `ImageView` и формировать новый документ, и это очень затратно как ресурсами, так и в силах(`html` разметку было бы  писать проще).

Если вы знаете, как лучше реализовать то, что описал, или же имеете свой способ, помогите. Спасибо.

Comment: По поводу вывода dosx не подскажу, а вот простую html разметку можно выводить в обычный TextView используя Html.fromHtml(тут_html_текст), но следует учитывать что возможности вывода довольно куцые.